# How to get the current local networks public facing IP address while connected to a vpn, using the terminal?

Tags: linux

Is there a command or file in Linux from which I can retrieve the public facing IP address for the Access Point(WiFi) that I am currently connected to while also being connected to a vpn? Reason I ask is because I would like for `curl wttr.in` to retrieve the weather information based on my current location and not the location of the vpn server I am connected to.
I have a script which runs in the background that retrieves the weather for whichever location I am in at the time and saves that information to a temporary file in which another script reads from. Like so.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

while true; do

    [ ! -f /tmp/weather_report.tmp ] && touch /tmp/weather_report.tmp

    curl "wttr.in?format=%C+%t" > /tmp/weather_report.tmp \
    || echo "..." > /tmp/weather_report.tmp

    sleep 300

done
```

Comment: If you gave your settings while the VPN is connected, this might help somebody have an idea: `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route; ip rule`

Comment: If your VPN has split tunneling enabled you can route traffic that's not destined for any of the VPN subnets out through your local network.  It split tunneling is disabled, you'll have to disconnect from your VPN to run your script.

Answer (score 0):

`curl ifconfig.me` will return your current public IP address

Comment: Yes, but when I am connected through a VPN it will return the VPN's public facing IP address and that is not what I am looking for. It is explained in my original post.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. Does your VPN service not provide the IP which you are connecting from? Check because you probably have a command to see it. If not, maybe you can check the log files of your VPN and you might find the IP there (then just need to run a simple script to retrieve it).

Comment: Unfortunately as of now I am only able to see the public IP address of the endpoint I am connected to and my private IP for the local network. I am using native wireguard on Linux.